# ASP.NET MVC Display ListItem object in Unordered List within View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following chunk of code:

```
@{

int draggableNumber = 0;
foreach (Data data in ViewBag.FieldNames)
{
    ListItem li = new ListItem();
    li.Attributes.Add("id", "draggable_" + draggableNumber);
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-primary ui-state-highlight");
    li.Text = data.ColumnName;
    li.Value = draggableNumber.ToString();

    @*<li id="draggable_@draggableNumber" class="btn btn-primary ui-state-highlight" style="white-space: normal;">field.ColumnName</li>*@

    draggableNumber++;
    ViewBag.ControlsToData.Add(li, data);
}
```

}

and I am trying to display the ListItem li object in my view like the commented section of the code. I have all the properties the ListItem needs to have for each ListItem. How can I display the ListItem to my view. I'm using Razor syntax.

Comment: `ListItem` is web forms, not MVC. You need to go to the MVC site and understand the basics of MVC and how to generate a view.

Comment: I think you are correct. I really do need to go out and learn the basics of MVC. I initially tried to do something similar to the accepted answer. But my coworker (who doesn't know much about MVC either), suggested I try to do what is shown above. I will look more into MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running everything in a code block, you just need to escape out of the code block to write to the output.

```
@{
    int draggableNumber = 0;
}
@foreach (Data data in ViewBag.FieldNames)
{
    @<li id="@("draggable_" + draggableNumber)">@field.ColumnName</li>
    draggableNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix WebForms controls into your razor views, it's not supported. However you can checkout this link about a quick workaround by Scott Hanselman. [Web forms and MVC razor views](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)